# Create a grayscale image from 16-bit data using C++

Tags: c++, image

I have an array of 16-bit values and I want to create an image (such as BMP) so that I can view it. Does anyone have suggestions of how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Not a full answer, but its's very easy to make [PGM images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example) without much thought.

Comment: Use a library like libgd, Qt, OpenCV or Image Magick or create the image files yourself. JPEG has its own C++ library

Comment: I should add that I am looking for something that is easy to use. I am not really a Windows programmer, so dont want to have to use something complicated. Thanks

Comment: Then you should try libgd. I didn't know it until now but the example seems pretty simple. A very short code to create an image

Comment: Please provide more context. What have you tried so far, what is is your specific problem. Also what color space are you in, is it RGB565, 16 bit gray-scale or something else?

Comment: The values are just 16-bit (white to black). I dont care how I do it just want each pixel displayed in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your image is 200px by 100px. Write the 20,000 16-bit vales to a binary file.

At the commandline, run **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -depth 16 -size 200x100 gray:yourFile.bin image.png
```

Or, if you want a JPG

```
magick ... image.jpg
```

For a tiny bit more effort, you could write a 16-bit PGM file which would have the benefit that it contains its dimensions and bit depth in a small ASCII header so the conversion in **ImageMagick** is simpler, and other programs such as **GIMP** can read it:

```
magick yourFile.pgm  image.jpg
```

The header would be:

```
P5
200 100
65535
... binary data as above ...
```

See [Wikipedia NetPBM article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

Comment: Thanks that seems like quite an easy solution.